# Linux - Bash - apply chown within many user directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs, chown

I have about 400 users on `/home/` directory.

I have a git repository on `/var/repos/my_repo.git`

I have cloned, using root account, this repository to all users on home folder through bash command.

Now I want to change the owner of cloned directory for each user, according to each folder.

Something like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name . -prune -exec chown {}:MY_GROUP {}/www/my_repo.git -R
```

It will not work because {} returns `./username`, so I just need a way to clean `./`

Somebody have a better solution?

Comment: Can't you just add the users to a group, then set the directory to a group and make the directory group rwx-able?

Comment: You should read this http://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine

Comment: Thanks Justin, I knew this post, I have it saved on Evernote. But I just wanna know if there a way to changing owner recursively. :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to indirectly achieve what you want, provided your `chown` version supports the `--reference` option. In this case, the command:

```
chown --reference=RFILE file_to_chown
```

where `RFILE` and `file_to_chown` are two files (or directories), will change owner and group of `file_to_chown` to match that of `RFILE`.

Since you want a special group, we'll need to use an auxilliary file that will be owned by user, and have group `MY_GROUP`. We'll use `mktemp` to create such a file.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

rfile=$(mktemp) || { echo "oops"; exit 1; }

for i in /home/*/; do
    [[ -d $i/www/my_repo.git ]] || continue
    chown --reference="$i" "$rfile"
    chown :MY_GROUP "$rfile" # or chgrp MY_GROUP "$rfile"
    chown -R --reference="$rfile" "$i/www/my_repo.git"
done
```

This method (using `--reference`) has the following advantage: a user's home name may be distinct from user's name.

The exact same approach without the temporary file, using the `my_repo.git` in user's home as a reference file.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for i in /home/*/; do
    [[ -d $i/www/my_repo.git ]] || continue
    chown --reference="$i" "$i/www/my_repo.git"
    chown :MY_GROUP "$i/www/my_repo.git" # or chgrp MY_GROUP "$i/www/my_repo.git"
    chown -R --reference="$i/www/my_repo.git" "$i/www/my_repo.git"
done
```

---

As a final note: if you want to check how the script behaves before running it, you can define (inside the script, before the `for` loop) a function `chown`:

```
chown() {
    echo "chown $@"
}
```

that will only show what's going to happen (minus the quotes), without executing anything. When you're happy, remove it from the script.

Comment: @LuizGustavoF.Gama: glad it helped you. I see you thanked the other people who answered you (and who provided valuable solutions). On StackOverflow, the best way to thank someone is to upvote his/her answer! please upvote their answer to show them you appreciate their help `;)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not properly recursing into subdirectories, `find` is just an unnecessary complication here.

```
for d in */www/my_repo.git; do
   chown -R "${d%%/*}:MY_GROUP "$d"
done
```

A much superior approach might have been to clone as the target user via `sudo` in the first place.

For completeness, a slightly ugly fix if you really want to use `find` could be

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name . -prune -exec sh -c 'chown "${1#./}:MY_GROUP "$1"/www/my_repo.git -R' _ {} \;
```

Comment: This approach will work when username and directory name is the same. This is usually the case. In some corner cases the owner of the directory may not be the same as the name of the directory itself. For a more elegant approach stat the owner of the home directory and then chown the repo directory, something like `chown $(stat -c %U ${d%%/*}):MY_GROUP "$d"`.

Comment: @altvis but now this fails if owner has no user name (e.g., has been deleted or not yet created). See my solution (with the `--reference` flag) to ensure 100% success.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the output of `ls` is usually a **very bad practice** but in this case you very likely **don't** have any directory with spaces in `/home`, so you can safely try the following

```
cd /home
ls | xargs -I% echo chown -R %:mygroup %/www/my_repo.git
```

Try it, it is in *DRY* mode (will only echo the `chown` command), if satisfied remove the `echo`.

Of course, you can also use the `find` command like so:

```
cd /home
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%f\0" | xargs -I% echo chown -R "%:mygroup" "%/www/my_repo.git"
```